# string comparison is shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a scenario to copy file from one server to another, for that i need to check any existing scp is in progress, have wrote a sample shell script but the condition is not being met even though syntax is correct, the main problem here is the output of `ps` command will gets stored in variable `scpstat` and the same compared for matching string in if statement, here I'm getting the output of the variable is different from executing outside of the script. can see it is formatted different in script execution when executing `sh -x scpsamp.sh`, why there is "`sh`" appended to the output, but while comparing without ps and assigning as `scpstat='scp'` i can able to get the condition correct, am i doing anything wrong while getting output in to the variable. please help

```
#!/bin/sh
scpstat=`ps -ef | grep scp | egrep -v 'grep|ssh' | awk '{print $8}')`  
if [ "$scpstat" = "scp" ];  
then  
echo "SCP is in progress"  
else  
echo "No SCP in progress"  
fi
```

[sh -x output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06fMW.png)

Comment: you can use `pdiof scp` and if it gives some process  id then there is scp connection going on. .

Comment: That's `pidof` for those playing along at home. But also `pgrep` is useful here.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/367921/how-to-prevent-ps-reporting-its-own-process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's notoriously difficult to extract information from the output of `ps`.  If your system has `pgrep`, it's much easier:

```
if pgrep scp >/dev/null
then
    echo "SCP is in progress"
else
    echo "No SCP in progress"
fi
```